# How to implement a lookup class in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, design-patterns, class-constants

I have a list of immutable value objects. The lookup class provides ways to iterate and query that data:

```
class Banker
  Bank = Struct.new(:name, :bic, :codes)

  attr_reader :banks
  def initialize
    @banks = [
      Bank.new('Citibank',    '1234567', ['1', '2']),
      Bank.new('Wells Fargo', '7654321', ['4']), # etc.
    ]
  end

  def find_by_bic(bic)
    banks.each do |bank|
      return bank if bank.bic == bic
    end
  end
end
```

`@banks` is initialized every time `Banker` is used. What options are there to cache `@banks` so that it's reused across different instances of the `Banker`?

Comment: I don't understand the reason of the downvote. I think the question and the problem is well explained. Please elaborate on what's missing!

Comment: The question is pretty clear to me, but its possible the downvoter felt question statement itself was slightly broad (I would disagree if that were the case). Or that the title doesn't quite match what you're actually asking (not really a downvotable reason imo).

Answer (score 4):

I don't think `Struct` buys you anything here. How about doing it like this?

**Code**

```
class Banker
  @all_banks = {}

  class << self
    attr_reader :all_banks
  end

  attr_reader :banks

  def initialize(banks)
    @banks = banks.keys
    banks.each { |k,v| self.class.all_banks[k] = v }
  end

  def find_by_bic(bic)
    return nil unless @banks.include?(bic)
    self.class.all_banks[bic]
  end
end
```

Note `self` in `self.class` is needed to distinguish the class of `self` from the keyword `class`.

**Example**

```
b1 = Banker.new({ '1234567' => { name: 'Citibank', codes: ["1", "2"] },
                  '7654321' => { name: 'Wells Fargo', codes: ['4'] } })
b1.banks
  #=> ["1234567", "7654321"]
Banker.all_banks
  #=> {"1234567"=>{:name=>"Citibank", :codes=>["1", "2"]},
  #    "7654321"=>{:name=>"Wells Fargo", :codes=>["4"]}}
b1.find_by_bic '7654321'
  #=> {:name=>"Wells Fargo", :codes=>["4"]}
b1.find_by_bic '1234567'
  #=> {:name=>"Citibank", :codes=>["1", "2"]}
b1.find_by_bic '0000000'
  #=> nil

b2 = Banker.new({ '6523155' => { name: 'Bank of America', codes: ["3"] },
                  '1234567' => { name: 'Citibank', codes: ["1", "2"] } })
b2.banks
  #=> ["6523155", "1234567"]
Banker.all_banks
  #=> {"1234567"=>{:name=>"Citibank", :codes=>["1", "2"]},
  #    "7654321"=>{:name=>"Wells Fargo", :codes=>["4"]},
  #    "6523155"=>{:name=>"Bank of America", :codes=>["3"]}}
b2.find_by_bic '6523155'
  #=> {:name=>"Bank of America", :codes=>["3"]}
b2.find_by_bic '1234567'
  #=> {:name=>"Citibank", :codes=>["1", "2"]}
b2.find_by_bic '7654321'
  #=> nil
```

**Alternatives**

If you prefer you could instead add the class method:

```
def self.new(banks)
  banks.each { |k,v| all_banks[k] = v }
  super
 end
```

and remove the first line in `initialize`.

Or, if you have a complete list of all banks, you could instead just make `all_banks` a constant:

```
ALL_BANKS = {"1234567"=>{:name=>"Citibank", :codes=>["1", "2"]},
             "7654321"=>{:name=>"Wells Fargo", :codes=>["4"]},
             "6523155"=>{:name=>"Bank of America", :codes=>["3"]}}

def find_by_bic(bic)
  return nil unless @banks.include?(bic)
  ALL_BANKS[bic]
end
```

and change `initialize` to:

```
def initialize(bics)
  @banks = bics
end
```

where `bics` is an array of `bic` values.

Answer (score 3):

To share immutable data between instances you can use frozen class variables: `@@banks ||= [...].freeze`